# Finding a Discord server ID with just a member ID connected to a voice channel

Tags: node.js, discord

So the discord bot (Discord v12) I'm designing in nodejs has a command that must go through a DM (it's a silent auction bot so the bid messages being sent as bids can't be seen).  Since I'm designing the bot to be able to be used on multiple servers I need a way to assign the server ID from the DM message so the bot knows the bid is for that particular server's auction.  Since it's a DM I can't pull the server ID from the message itself.

The only way I've thought to accomplish this is by having the members logged into a voice channel of the server, but I can't figure out a way to pull the server ID from the voice channel itself.  Is there a way to pull the voice channel ID a member ID is currently logged into and pull the server ID from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information regarding a voice channel where the user is logged with the [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceState) object.

You can get it from a member's [.voice](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice) attribute.

Comment: Yeah my issue is I can't use member since the message will be coming from a DM, so it will come out as null.  I've been looking to see if I can pull the voice channel ID and get the server ID from there, but everything I've been looking at requires the server ID initially to get information.